# Como passar o campo de um struct para uma função numa biblioteca a parte?

Tags: c, struct

Olá, pessoal.

Estou com um programa que tem uma struct assim:

`struct itemDeLista{
        char nomeProd[10];
        float quant;
        float vUnit;
        int item;
    };`

Mas preciso contar a quantidade de letras na string nomeProd[10], como o professor pediu que nós não usássemos a string.h estou fazendo a função strlen numa biblioteca própria, estou recebendo o char pelo scanf mas quando passo para a função da biblioteca, acontece alguns erros. Vou colocar o código inteiro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "biblio.h"

struct itemDeLista{
    char nomeProd[10];
    float quant;
    float vUnit;
    int item;
};

struct itemDeLista valores;

int main(){
  int k = 0;

  scanf("%[A-Z a-z]",valores.nomeProd);
  printf("%s\n", valores.nomeProd);
  k = strcnt(valores);
  printf("%d", k);
return(0);
}
```

Este é o programa principal, a seguir é a biblioteca e a função pra contar a quantidade de caracteres.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int strcnt(struct itemDeLista m);

int strcnt(struct itemDeLista m){
   int i = 0, cont = 0;
   while(1){
      if(m.nomeProd[i] != '\0'){
      cont++;
      }
    else{
        break;
    }
    i++;
  }
return(cont);
}
```

Agradeço muito o help, valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a definição da `struct` no programa principal a biblioteca não tem informação sobre ela.

Tens de colocar a definição da `struct itemDeLista` num ficheiro a que ambos os "sources" tenham acesso; por exemplo: itemDeLista.h

```
// itemDeLista.h
#ifndef ITEMDELISTA_H
#define ITEMDELISTA_H
struct itemDeLista {
    char nomeProd[10];
    float quant;
    float vUnit;
    int item;
};
#endif
```

Depois incluis este header nos teus programas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "biblio.h"
#include "itemDeLista.h"

struct itemDeLista valores;

int main(void) {
    int k = 0;

    scanf("%9[A-Z a-z]", valores.nomeProd);
    printf("%s\n", valores.nomeProd);
    k = strcnt(valores);
    printf("%d\n", k);
    return(0);
}
```

e no source da tua biblioteca

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "itemDeLista.h"

int strcnt(struct itemDeLista m);

int strcnt(struct itemDeLista m) {
    int i = 0, cont = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (m.nomeProd[i] != '\0') {
            cont++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Se o header "biblio.h" já tem a definição da `struct` tens de inclui-lo na biblioteca.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui. Uma pergunta, nesse formato de header compartilhado pros dois, eu consigo: valores.quant = 15, por exemplo, nos dois arquivos?

Comment: Consegues, mas não é aconselhável usar variáveis globais. É melhor usares uma variável normal dentro do main e passar o seu endereço para outras funções.